# Update multiple columns from one text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to parse an input from a single form field to update 3 columns in the table.  I created a custom attribute and defined my own `setter` and `getter` methods to use in the form.  The problem I'm having is how to set the actually column data.  It doesn't seem to take the input.

My setter is as follows:

```
    def humanized_ingredient=(value)
        parsed = Ingreedy.parse(value)
        write_attribute(:amount, parsed.amount) 
        write_attribute(:name, parsed.ingredient) 
        write_attribute(:unit, parsed.unit)
    end
```

I have the new humanized_ingredient in the `params` white list but it doesn't seem to do anything to the amount, name or unit.  There isn't any errors in the server console.  I've also tried this

```
    def humanized_ingredient=(value)
            parsed = Ingreedy.parse(value)
            self.name = parsed.ingredient
            self.amount = parsed.amount
            self.unit = parsed.unit
    end
```

Here's the view as well:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-11 columns">
        <%= f.text_field :humanized_ingredient %>
    </div>
    <div class="small-1 columns">
        <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
        <%= link_to "Remove", '#', :onclick => h("remove_fields(this)"), class: "btn", title: "Remove Ingredient", remote: true %>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Have no idea why it isn't taking the params

Edit:  I'm an idiot and shouldn't code on little sleep. So I forgot that i had reject_if on my accepts_nested_attributes in my parent model...thought I got all the validation checks.  Apparently that one doesn't give any kind of output when it rejects so it wasn't popping up in the logs as being rejected and was just not processing the data.  Everything is working as expected now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This might be helpful**

```
@column_value = params[:column_value]
@table = Table.New
@table.column1 = @column_value
@table.column2 = @column_value
@table.column3 = @column_value
```

or you can use setter also

```
def column_value=(value)
  self.column1 = value
  self.column2 = value
  self.column3 = value
end
```

remember you have to use :column_value in form also as attribute

**if this is not still working please check you have permitted :column_value parameter**

```
def params_table
 params.require(:table).permit(:column_value)
end
```

Comment: ive tried that if you look at the code I posted it is the same as what you got (just with my names for the fields) but it doesnt update the fields

Comment: Did you forgot to permit :humanized_ingredient ? To use setter you must permit parameter first.

Comment: its being called as a nested attribute and it is included in the params list of the parent controller.  It is being accepted and the server console doesnt say its rejecting it like it would if I forgot to add it (which has happened before)

Comment: I think It would be easy to understand how you want to save data i.e. table structure and relationship.

Comment: Im trying to have a single form input for a recipe ingredient item so users can put something like "3 cups rice" and then I want to save the 3 to the amount column in my ingredient table, cups to the unit column and rice to the name column

Comment: I think you are using nested_form_attributes_for ingredient in recipe form. can you please edit your question and add details.

Comment: I found the problem, thank you for the help, it got me looking through all the relationships closer and forget the reject_if on my accepts_nested_attributes in the parent model